# How can I draw like this picture?

Tags: chemfig, chemistry, mhchem, chemmacros

[image]

I can not make code for this picture.

Comment: As there are different ways to approach this, I would strongly suggest that you come up with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried so far and helps understand in which context you want to use this. You could use a simple table for example, but maybe this is not sufficient for your needs. I don't understand what "Text1" etc. are supposed to denote. For the chemical formulae, you could use the `mhchem` for example (the package also provides the arrows shown). Also note that the small font in the picture is very hard to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am totally not sure whether this is somewhere close to what you're after, but maybe it can help you in some way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz, siunitx} 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\DeclareSIUnit\M{\textsc{m}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{NiceTabular}{cccccl}
%
\ce{CH3COOH_{(aq)}} & \ce{<=>} & \ce{H^+_{(aq)}} & \ce{+} & \ce{CH3COO^-_{(aq)}} & \\
\qty{0.1}{\M} & & 0 & & 0 & \textbf{Text 1} \\
$(0.1-x)$\,\si{\M} & & $x$\,\si{\M} & & $x$\,\si{\M} & \textbf{Text 2} \\
%
\ce{CH3COONa_{(s)}} & \ce{->} & \ce{Na^+_{(aq)}} & \ce{+} & \ce{CH3COO^-_{(aq)}} & \\
\qty{0.1}{\M} & & 0 & & 0 & \textbf{Text 3} \\
0 & & \qty{0.1}{\M} & & \qty{0.1}{\M} & \textbf{Text 4} \\
%
 & & & & \textbf{Text 5} & \\
%
\CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw[dashed, rounded corners] (1-|5) rectangle (7-|6);
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Jasper, is there any reason you specified `[version=4]`?

Comment: @anis The package issues a warning if you don't specify a `version` and the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) suggests that it is a good idea to do so. Obviously, the package has been revised over time and as far as I understand, some functions are only available in their current specification if you load the package using `version=4`. The reason for this is to be backwards compatible.

Comment: Please note the letter M used for the unit symbol should be upright, so you might want to use `siunitx` package. Small caps would be even better, and 'mol/l' in place of 'M' would be ideal ([How are lowercase m and uppercase M used in general chemistry courses?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/115196)).

Comment: @andselisk Thanks for pointing that out. I was not sure about that and the picture was not too clear to me. I edited my answer accordingly.